# How Do Accelerated Electrons Between Electrodes Cause Ionization of Gas Molecules?

Tags: electromagnetism, collision, gas, ionization-energy

Due to small number of free electrons in gases these electrons are accelerated in electric field which creates collisions with gas molecules causing an ionization of molecules. I am not sure how do collisions cause ionization? In collisions high speed electron can transfer momentum on molecules which can increase any type of their kinetic energy (translational, rotational, vibrational), but how does this process cause valence electrons to leave molecules?

Comment: Electron-electron scattering for example. Only a few eV has to be transferred, so ~100eV electrons do a fine job.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerated electrons scatter off the outer electrons of the gas molecules. If they hit one of those electrons hard enough to transfer ~several electron volts of energy to it, they can temporarily knock it out of its orbital, ionizing the gas. that loose electron is then available to be accelerated by the field and thereby participate in conducting electricity through the gas.

Of course, the loose electron is also available to recombine with another gas ion and stop drifting, but if there are enough electrons drifting through the gas and being re-accelerated by the field between collisions, the *gas discharge* becomes *self-sustaining*.

Comment: Ohh, yes yes. Thank you. What is important here is interaction between free electron and valence electrons or in molecules it is better say outer shell electrons and in this collision there is a transfer of energy. If gained energy of electron is bigger than ionization energy of molecule/atom, ions are created.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the threshold is the ionization energy. This is considered a scattering event, where your electron transfers (part of) its momentum (kinetic energy) to another electron in the outer shells (valence electron).

> In physics and chemistry, ionization energy (American English spelling) or ionisation energy (British English spelling) is the minimum amount of energy required to remove the most loosely bound electron of an isolated neutral gaseous atom or molecule.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kqgY.jpg)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy

If the amount of transferred energy meets or exceeds the valence electron's ionization energy, then that electron gets kicked off the atom (molecule) and contributes to the electric conductivity of the gas (or joins another atom).

[image]

> Charged particles create an ionization track, around which the liquid vaporizes, forming microscopic bubbles. Bubble density around a track is proportional to a particle's energy loss.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_chamber

The most beautiful example of this is the bubble chamber, where the electron ionizes the atoms or molecules along its path, thereby losing kinetic energy and spiraling inwards.

Comment: Thank you for a long answer :). I figured ionization energy is important here. What I didn't know is that interaction or collision between free and valence eletrons is what is crucial for energy transfer which causes ionization.